# FileWriter throw a numberformatexception

Tags: java, filewriter, numberformatexception

```
                if (bsave == e.getSource()) {
        path=null;
        try {
            getpath();
        } catch(Exception ee) {
            JOptionPane ss=new JOptionPane();
            ss.showMessageDialog(this,"Something wrong with the path....maybe Chinese name....");
        }
        if (path==null) return ;
        setTitle(path);
        try {
            File file=new File(path);   
            if(!file.exists()) file.createNewFile(); 
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String myreadline=textf.getText();
            if (ty==0) {
                if (fw==null) System.out.println(fw);
                System.out.println(ty);
                bw.write(myreadline);
            } if (ty==1) {
                int len=myreadline.length();
                for (int i=0;i<len;i+=8) {
                    bw.write((char) chan.parseInt(myreadline.substring(i,i+7),2));
                }
            } else {
                int len=myreadline.length();
                for (int i=0;i<len;i+=2)
                    bw.write((char) chan.parseInt(myreadline.substring(i,i+1),16));
            }
            br.close();  
            fr.close();
        } catch(Exception e0) {
            System.out.println(e0.toString());
        }           
    }
```

In total it is like this...But as it output a "0", so it must be there?

java.lang.NumberFormatException： For input string: "T" "

The string `myreadline` is start with "T"
So it try to change it into a number ... while writing?
I got really confused..

Comment: The `FileWriter` class (or any of the other classes present here) would never throw a `NumberFormatException`. Is this all of your code? Are you sure the error comes from this part of the code?

Comment: can you paste the full code and input file

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: paste the relevant code and exception stack trace.

Comment: I miss an else..So it goes to the third part an get that...

Answer (score 0):

As commented in the post above, `FileWriter` will not throw a `NumberFormatException`. Check your code around `bw.write((char) chan.parseInt(myreadline.substring(i,i+7),2));` . Here you are parsing from String into an Integer.

Easiest way to debug will be to surround such lines in a `try-catch(RuntimeException){}` block and carefully check the exception stacktrace.